# Texture not applied correctly

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

I baked Ambient Occlusion on top of a texture. Every area receives the matching colors except for the front legs below the knees. When in UV Editing Mode, I see that the legs are indeed in the texture and should reveive color -- but they don't. What is the reason for this? I already checked for interior faces and whether the normals face the correct direction. [image: The Leg is selected but appears black in the 3D viewport.]

Comment: do you have multiple materials on that object?

Comment: @David no, only the Ambient Occlusion bake

Comment: Uploading your .blend might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

What David was asking is, have the lower front legs been assigned different Materials than the rest of the giraffe?

In Edit mode select all of the giraffe, open the Materials menu and select the material that the upper body is using then Hit the Assign button.
[image]

Comment: oh my god this worked.. I thought it's enough to just hook up the texture in the shader graph. Thank you! Do you happen to know how I can increase the sampling rate for the ambient occlusion baking?